# Automatically detele old Facebook posts

Tags: facebook

I'm currently cleaning up my Facebook account to make it more professional. I wanted to delete all my old posts instead of making a new account because I have a large network right now. Is there a way to delete your posts automatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming at all

Comment: While it's not tradition programming, it certainly isn't English. But after searching 'reasons off'topic on stack overflow' I realize now that stackoverflow is actually one of many stack exchange communitees and there are probably better suited areas for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this seems long, but it's just because I wrote out every little step to remove any guess work.

1.Open Chrome or Firefox 
2. Download 'iMacros' addon 
3. Restart the browser 
4. Log in to FB, go to your profile 
5. Go to your ACTIVITY LOG(CLick down arrow in top right of screen > activity log) 
6. Go to YOUR POSTS(In the left side-panel) 
7. Click on the iMacros icon on your browser 
8. A side-bar should slide out on the left of the screen. Open the 'Rec' tab 
9. Select 'Record' in iMacro side-bar 
 10. Go through the process of deleting a post. The macro will record your actions so only do what's necessary (click pencil, click delete, approve delete in pop-up) 
 11. Select 'Stop' in iMacro side-bar 
 12. Right click the recording you just made('#Current.iim') and select 'Edit Macro' 
 13. You should see something pretty similar to this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX<br> TAB T=1
URL GOTO=//www.facebook.com/YOURNAME/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_11
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:mrs<SP>_2fmu<SP>img<SP>sp_AsQNWzugZQW<SP>sx_ded844&&TXT:
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete<br> 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:u_y_1 ATTR=TXT:Delete<SP>Post
```

Now comes the tricky part, pay close attention.

14.Replace your first 2 lines:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
```

With:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

It's okay if your version build number is different, you can use the one above anyways.

15.Keep your original 'URL GOTO' the same, but delete everything under that 
 16. Under your original 'URL GOTO', copy and paste the following lines:

```
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,40000)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:_55pe&&TXT: 
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=class:_s ATTR=TXT:Delete<SP>Post 
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

17. Click 'Save & Close'
18. Open the 'Play' tab in the iMacro left side-bar
19. Click 'Play', the code will run once
20. Make sure your most recent post was actually deleted
21. Under the 'Play' tab there is a repeat macro section. Set max value to '9999'
22. Click 'Play (Loop)'. It will then begin the time consuming, but now automated process of deleting your posts.
23. Check back every once in a while to make sure everything is working properly

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Graph API?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#deleting